# How to control spacing in formulas inside a table?

Tags: tables, amsmath

I have the following table:

```
\documentclass[12pt, twoside]{report}
\usepackage[a4paper,width=150mm, top=25mm, bottom=25mm, bindingoffset=6mm]{geometry}
\usepackage[backend=biber,style=numeric,hyperref=true]{biblatex}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{makecell}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\raggedbottom

\begin{document}
\bgroup
\def\arraystretch{1.5}
\begin{table}[!ht]
    \caption{Definition of $mapToReference()$}
    \label{tab:op_map_read_to_reference}
    {\begin{tabular}{l|p{12cm}}
    \toprule
    Inputs & \hangindent=1em$M_{raw} = \{m_i: m_i = (header, payload)\}$ where $m.payload = r = (s\_id, r\_id, b, q, f_p)$ as in. \\
    \cline{2-2}
    Operation & $mapToReference(r, ref\_id)$\\
    \cline{2-2}
    \multirow{2}{*}{Outputs} & \hangindent=1em$M_{aln} = \{m_i: m_i = (header, r)\} \text{ where } r = (s\_id, ref\_id, r\_id, b, q, f_p, rname, pos, mapq, cigar, flags)$\\
    & \hangindent=1em $M_{unaln} = \{m_i: m_i = (header, r)\} \text{  where } r = (s\_id, r\_id, b, q, f_p, unmapped=true)$\\
    \bottomrule
    \end{tabular}}
\end{table}
\egroup
\end{document}
```

This is generating an ugly looking table where the formulas, especially in the Output section are stretched out. I'm wondering what the best way is to control the layout of these cells. I don't want arbitrary horizontal spacing, and I want to be able to introduce line breaks wherever I want.

Thanks.

Comment: probably you want `\raggedright` but also use `\mathrm{header}` or `\mathit{header}` etc, never math italic for multi-letter words it spaces the letters out so they look like a product of single letter variables.

Answer (score 3):

Some suggestions:

- Use explicit math italics, rather than ordinary math mode, to typeset variable names; in the code below, this is achieved via the `\vn` ("variable name") macro.
- Use explicit line breaks.
- Use fewer pairs of curly braces: Many of them do absolutely nothing except create code clutter.

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt, twoside]{report}
\usepackage[a4paper,width=150mm, vmargin=25mm, 
            bindingoffset=6mm]{geometry}
\usepackage{array,booktabs,ragged2e,amsmath}
\raggedbottom
\newcommand\vn[1]{\mathit{#1}}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[!ht]
\def\arraystretch{1.25}
    \caption{Definition of $\vn{mapToReference}()$}
    \label{tab:op_map_read_to_reference}
    \centering
    \begin{tabular}{@{}l>{\RaggedRight}p{12cm}@{}}
    \toprule
    Inputs & $\vn{M_{raw}} = \{m_i: m_i = (\vn{header}, \vn{payload})\}$ where \\
    & \qquad $\vn{m.payload} = r = (s\_id, r\_id, b, q, f_p)$ as in. \\
    \cmidrule(l){2-2}
    Operation & $\vn{mapToReference}(r, \vn{ref\_id})$\\
    \cmidrule(l){2-2}
    Outputs & $\vn{M_{aln}} = \{m_i: m_i = (\vn{header}, r)\}$, 
    where \\
    & \qquad $r = (s\_id, \vn{ref}\_id, r\_id, b, q, f_p, 
    \vn{rname}, \vn{pos}, \vn{mapq}, \vn{cigar}, \vn{flags})$\\
    & $\vn{M_{unaln}} = \{m_i: m_i = (\vn{header}, r)\}$, where \\
    & \qquad $r = (s\_id, r\_id, b, q, f_p, \vn{unmapped=true})$\\
    \bottomrule
    \end{tabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```